# Iframe PDF Change page on click url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, iframe

I want to go between pages inside a PDF File contained in a IFRAME by just clicking on a link.

This is what i made so far:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return pagina(10);">Pagina 10</a>
<iframe name="ifrx" id="ifrx" src="1430263377Physic.pdf" style="height:800px; width:1170px">
```

Script:

```
<script>
    function pagina(pag) {
        $("#ifrx").attr('src','').delay(100).attr('src','1430263377Physic.pdf#page='+pag);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

But doesn't work, im trying to achieve this but with no luck.

Comment: Are you so sure it's possible to do it like this?

Comment: Dont know if it's possible that's why im trying.

Answer (score 1):

Change `attr` to `prop`. Like that:

```
function pagina(pag) {
    $("#ifrx").prop('src','1430263377Physic.pdf#page='+pag);

    return false;
}
```

Attribute is used to set initial value of iframe object property when parsing, but when you're changing the attribute, value doesn't populate to property.

By the way, as far as I know, there is no need to clear `src`, wait and set it to right value.

**UPDATE:**

I checked this approach for websites ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/erykpiast/rv6hwt6p/1/)). I guess it's impossible for PDFs, so replacing iframe with new one, with updated `src` can be only possible way to do it.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed you want to change hash part of URL! I know it may looks hacky and ugly, but replacing `iframe` with new one, with updated URL, should work out of the box.

Comment: That work well for me. Removing and appdending a new iframe works. Thanks !

Comment: Does changing the page number dynamically using JS/jQuery reload the pdf every time from the server or is it like scrolling to particular id tag in html?